# Fetching relations with different types

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

I have following structures:

ObjectX:

```
(id: UUID, name: String, title: String)
```

ObjectY (mapping table):

```
(objectZId: UUID, objectXId: UUID)
```

And i'm trying to fetch `ObjectX` by `objectZId` with following code:

```
val objectXByZ = RelationIds[ObjectY, UUID]("byObjectZId", c => Seq(c.objectZId))
implicit val objectXId = HasId[ObjectX, UUID](_.id)

val objectX = Fetcher.rel[GraphQLContext, ObjectX, ObjectY, UUID](
    (ctx: GraphQLContext, objectXIds: Seq[UUID]) =>
      ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectXByIds(objectXIds)(ctx.trace),
    (ctx: GraphQLContext, rels: RelationIds[XobjectX]) =>
      ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectYByX(rels(objectXByZ))(ctx.trace)
  )
```

and then using it here:

...

```
implicit val textX: ObjectType[GraphQLContext, ObjectX] = deriveObjectType(AddFields(
  Field(
    name = "objectX",
    fieldType = ListType(objectXType),
    resolve = c => TestFetchers.objectX.deferRelSeq(
      TestFetchers.objectXByZ, c.value.id
    )
)
```

...

But getting errors:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.fevo.coco.nut.models.ObjectX]]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.fevo.coco.nut.models.ObjectY]]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]       ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectYByX(rels(objectXByZ))(ctx.trace)
[error]                                                    ^
[info] scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.fevo.coco.nut.models.ObjectX]] <: scala.concurrent.Future[Seq[com.fevo.coco.nut.models.ObjectY]]?
[info] false
```

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49833732/can-not-understand-fetcher-rel/49861528#49861528) I need to use same types in fetcher, but is there a way to use different types?

---

Another problem is when I use same type in fetcher:

```
val objectX = Fetcher.rel[GraphQLContext, ObjectX, ObjectX, UUID](
  (ctx: GraphQLContext, objectXIds: Seq[UUID]) =>
    ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectXByIds(objectXIds)(ctx.trace),
  (ctx: GraphQLContext, rels: RelationIds[XobjectX]) =>
    ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectYByX(rels(objectXByZ))(ctx.trace)
  )
```

i'm not getting any results (getObjectYByX executes, but getObjectXByIds does not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fetcher`s have support for intermediate data structures when you are loading relation data from the database. The type of this intermediate data structure is provided via `RelRes` type parameter.

In your case, when you are loading `ObjectX` from the database based on the `objectZId`, you also need to tell fetcher how loaded `ObjectX` relates to one (or several) of the provided `objectZId`s (since you are loading multiple relations at once). This is where the intermediate data structure comes into play. In your case, it can be as simple as a tuple `(ObjectY, ObjectX)`:

```
val objectXByZ = Relation[ObjectX, (ObjectY, ObjectX), UUID]("byObjectZId", 
  intermediate ⇒ Seq(intermediate._1.objectZId),
  intermediate ⇒ intermediate._2)

val objectX = Fetcher.rel[GraphQLContext, ObjectX, (ObjectY, ObjectX), UUID](
  (ctx, objectXIds) ⇒ ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectXByIds(objectXIds)(ctx.trace),
  // returns list of tuples: Future[Seq[(ObjectY, ObjectX)]]
  (ctx, rels) ⇒ ctx.app.service.Service.getObjectXRelationsByZIds(rels(objectXByZ))(ctx.trace))
```